# When to use past tense on event listener?

Tags: android, design-patterns

When should I use past tense on event listener?  If you check the android link below, you can see `onFocusChange` on `View` and `onFocusChanged` on `WebView`.  Which one should be more appropriate and why android choose present tense on `View` and pass tense on `WebView`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: The convention is to write event-methods in past tense. There are exceptions like the one you found, probably because it didn't sound like a proper English to the engineer that wrote `onFocusChange` (but `focusChanged` would have sounded better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onFocusChange` in the example looks more like a lapse in the method naming and was likely meant to read `onFocusChanged`. In both examples (according to the docs) the event is sent *after* the action has taken place. Thus past tense would be appropiate.

Events that are sent after the action has taken place that they inform about should use past tense. If events are sent before the action takes place you probably don't want to use past tense. `beforeFocusChange` or `focusAboutToChange` are patterns that I've come across.

Comment: `View.OnClickListener` has method `onClick`, `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` has `onItemClick` and many more examples in the Android API. So one could argue the present tense is the norm and `onFocusChanged` is an accident.

Comment: While it might be the norm in the Android SDK, there are other libraries. For example, SWT, Swing, AWT and many the Eclipse APIs use past tense to indicate listener methods that are called 'after the fact'.

Comment: I agree with you that there is not, unfortunately, a naming standard when inventing event method names on Android. When I found this question here was because I was looking for a naming standard on Android. No luck though :(